# How to install R version 3.2.1 – collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: command-line, software-installation, make, configure, r

I'm trying to install R version 3.2.1. I executed the following code

```
./configure --enable-R-shlib
```

followed by `make` command. But the following error is obtained.

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../appl/dchdc.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../appl/dchdc.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me to resolve this or let me know how to remove this specific version of R. Because when I run `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove R`,

```
E: Unable to locate package R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For a full list of steps to install a version from source, skip the following lines and read on with **Install from source***

---

To install/remove the *GNU R statistical computation and graphics system* you need the package `r-base`.

Therefore

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge r-base
```

---

To install/remove the *GNU R collection of recommended packages*  you need `r-recommended`

```
sudo apt-get install r-recommended
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install r-recommended
```

---

### Install from source

The version 3.2.1 is in the [Wily Universe](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=r-base) repositories.

**To install the version 3.2.1 on older Ubuntu versions, you have to compile the packages for yourself**

1. Download and extract

   ```
   cd
   wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.2.1.tar.gz
   sudo apt-get install tcl tcl-dev tk-dev tk 
   tar xf R-3.2.1.tar.gz
   cd R-3.2.1
   ```
2. Create a Makefile with `configure` and enable shared libraries (`--enable-R-shlib`) and Tcl/TK-support (`--with-tcltk`)

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-R-shlib --with-tcltk
   ```

   or simply with (**without** `shared libraries`)

   ```
   ./configure
   ```
3. And start the build process

   ```
   make
   ```
4. After that, install. I prefer the installation with `checkinstall`, to create and install a deb package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   But you could also use the standard way

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

---

And now, you have version 3.2.1 installed

```
 % /usr/local/bin/R

R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) -- "World-Famous Astronaut"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

>
```

---

### Install RStudio Desktop

Download the latest version [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/), e.g.

```
wget https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-0.99.467-amd64.deb
```

Install via

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-0.99.467-amd64.deb
```

Check the install output and install missing packages, e.g. in my case

```
sudo apt install libjpeg62
```

Start RStudio via Unity Dash or GNOME Activities or via command line

```
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio
```

[image]

Comment: There is no typo error. I tried the above code. But I got the previous error followed by these error                                                                      `make[3]: *** [libR.so] Error 1`
`make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/niyas/Downloads/R-3.2.1/src/main'`
`make[2]: *** [R] Error 2`
`make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/niyas/Downloads/R-3.2.1/src/main'`
`make[1]: *** [R] Error 1`
`make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/niyas/Downloads/R-3.2.1/src'`
`make: *** [R] Error 1`

Comment: I can install R 3.2.1 using the following code.. `./configure`    `make`    `sudo make install` . But when I pass `--enable-R-shlib` to the configuration script it will throw the above error. And I can't open Rstudio without enabling R-Shlib. It throws an error `If this is a custom build of R, was it built with the --enable-R-shlib option?`

Comment: It's a typo `./configure--enable-R-shlib` gives `bash: ./configure--enable-R-shlib: No such file or directory`

Comment: remove your source folder and follow my instructions step by step

Comment: Thanks. Successfully installed R. But still I can't launch R studio..It throws a message `R shared library (/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so) not found. If this is a custom build of R, was it built with the --enable-R-shlib option?`  I have been working on this for a week. I'm going mad on this. Please help.

Comment: Have you started `./configure` with `--enable-R-shlib`?

Comment: Yes. I did exact 5 steps in your answer. And I tried to manually copy the libR.so file, but it the permission got denied. Btw, I'm the admin.

Comment: Give me a second, I'm building the packages again.

Comment: RStudio Desktop 0.99.467?

Comment: Yes. rstudio-0.99.467-amd64

Comment: Ok, go into the source folder and start a `make uninstall; make clean` and start the whole procedure again.

Comment: @Niyas: what's the result of the last command?

Comment: @Fabby The source folder is in my home directory. But I can't navigate to the source folder through terminal. Is there any command? It says, there is no directory R 3.2.1, but it is there. My file path is home/R-3.2.1

Comment: `/home/R-3.2.1/` ? Really?

Comment: I hope, `/home/R-3.2.1/` is really the source folder and **not your** home folder. Delete the folder with `sudo rm -r /home/R-3.2.1`

Comment: I said /home/R-3.2.1/ is my source folder. I executed the above command. And it says `rm: cannot remove ‘/home/R-3.2.1’: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Ok, what is the output of `sudo ls -la --escape /home`

Comment: total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096 May 16  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root  root  4096 Feb  8 11:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x 38 niyas niyas 4096 Aug  2 20:46 niyas

Comment: As you can see, there is no `/home/R-3.2.1`. Remove the folder inside **your** home folder. I assume `/home/niyas/R-3.2.1`. Therefore `rm -r /home/niyas/R-3.2.1`

Comment: Thanks. I have removed the directory and uninstalled R. But I can access R 3.2.1 by command line even though it is not in software center.  How is that possible?

Comment: How did you uninstall the program? The Software Center and an installation with `make install` are completely different things. Therefore the hint to install with `checkinstall` as you can read in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26521/discussion-between-niyas-and-a-b).

Comment: @Pilot6 Test test

Comment: @A.B. It worked. Thanks a lot. I have been working on this for almost a week.

Answer (score -1):

If you encounter following error:

```
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

run this command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep r-base
```

Comment: You really should explain what this does and why it will help.